# How can I get my webpack-dev server to open on my phone?

Tags: webpack, localhost, port, webpack-dev-server, lan

I'm having trouble connecting my mobile phone to my webpack dev server.
I'm using the Angular Starter Kit: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter.

My phone and macbook are in the same wifi network and I'm trying to access it on my phone's browser using: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000 (local ip of mac and server port.) I have also set the flag --host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (my local ip) on the webpack server config.

I might be missing something as I've never really done this before. Is there any other thing that can prevent me from connecting to dev server? What else should I check?

My phone always responds with:
'Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding.'

What's strange is that using the coda text editor, the phone can connect to the server it's creating with the same method.
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57835